# Is there anyway to concatenate select query columns when result is show?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For example I have a query:

```
select item_name, day, month, year from some_table;
```

But I want resulting table to be 2 columns, not 4, like that:

> [Item name][Date (dd.mm.YYYY)]

Can we do that?

I use Google's Biq Query standard SQL.

Comment: Which `RDBMS` ?

Comment: And why are you storing time components separately in the first place?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I use Google's BiqQuery standard SQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - DB structure is made not by me. I can't change it, but having date is single column will ease my programming job a lot.

Comment: Can't you use something like `CONCAT()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT item_name, DATE(year, month, day) AS date
FROM `yourTable`
```

you can test / play with it using below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 'abc' AS item_name, 5 AS day, 10 AS month, 2017 AS year UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 1, 9, 2017
)
SELECT item_name, DATE(year, month, day) AS date
FROM `yourTable`
```

Answer (score 2):

use this query

```
select item_name, CONCAT(cast(day as STRING)) ,'.' ,cast(month as STRING), '.',cast(year as STRING)) as Date
```

Comment: Got this error: `Error: No matching signature for operator + for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: INT64 + INT64; FLOAT64 + FLOAT64 at [1:26]`

Comment: select item_name, CONCAT(cast(day as STRING)) ,'.' ,cast(month as STRING), '.',cast(year as STRING) as Date

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`CONCAT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#concat)**

**Query**

```
select item_name, concat(day, '.', month, '.', year) as date
from some_table;
```

If the columns are in integer type, then you have to cast it to string.

```
select item_name,
concat(cast(day as string), '.', cast(month as string), '.', cast(year as string)) as date
from some_table;
```

Comment: Thank you. That is also worked. Good alternative solutions for `Date` one.